# Constraints validation without Form with Play2.6

Tags: scala, playframework

I got following errors after upgraded play framework from 2.5 to 2.6.
(It was able to compile with 2.5)
Scala version: 2.11.8

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method emailAddress in trait Constraints of type => play.api.data.validation.Constraint[String]
[error] and  method emailAddress in trait Constraints of type (errorMessage: String)play.api.data.validation.Constraint[String]
[error] match argument types (String)
[error] Constraints.emailAddress("test@sample.com")
                    ^
```

Is there any way to use methods under Constraints with Play 2.6?

```
import play.api.data.validation._

val result = Constraints.emailAddress("test@sample.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

emailAddress is a method which internally calls the another overridden method emailAddress(errorMessage: String = "error.email") method so if you call emailAddress with parameter that will give compilation error, so you can test it like this

```
val result = Constraints.emailAddress

    result("test@sample.com")
```